# My German National Work Visa Got Rejected due to Submitted Provisional Master Degree Certificate

Tags: visa, blue-card

Recently I have received heartbreaking news from German Consulate Bangalore stating that "The Bachelor degree (Bachelor of Arts) submitted is not registered as a recognised degree in Germany. The Master degree (MCA) is only provisional. We need the final degree. Thus one of the requirements for a Blue Card EU was not meet and visa could not be granted".

I have recently in December 2018 completed my Master Degree and here in India firstly University Provide Official Transcript (Final Degree Grade Card) along with Provisional Pass certificate and thereafter exactly one year the convocation will take place and Final Degree Certificate will be handed over to students. So I have submitted the Provisional Certificate along with Official Transcript but The Visa Officer is not kept the Official Transcript and as a result, I got rejection.

Both the degree is listed in annabin list except my bachelor degree university is not listed. So please if anyone familiar with this situation kindly suggest to me.

Comment: I'm unclear what suggestions you want. It sounds like their refusal was correct and consistent with other refusals of that nature. *shrug* Did you want to try applying again after you've got the final degree? Or maybe try another country? Or maybe forget the whole effort entirely, saving yourself time, money, and more heartbreak, and remain in India?

Comment: There are two reasons for the refusal of my National Visa for Blue Card. I am wondering If I again apply with my Master Degree Official Transcript , which is not received proper attention, is there any hope of success? Or should I have to get recognised my Bachelor Degree from ZAB?. Today I have seen my university, and my bachelor degree both are available in annabin list with H+.

Comment: I wouldn't bother applying until applying until I fulfilled every requirement to the letter. But that's just me. I think doing anything else except what they specifically ask for only invites more heartbreak. And if you'll forgive the stereotypes, Germans tend to be very literal. If they say something, they usually mean exactly what they have said, with little room for 'proper consideration'.

Comment: Did It work out for you? Did the embassy accept the provisional certificate later or did you have to submit the original only? Can you please tell how things ended eventually because I’m in a very similar situation! It’d be great if you could help! Thanks!

Comment: did you have any luck in getting the visa things sorted?
I have the same situation currently, I have my visa appointment soon and I don't have my bachelor's degree - I have applied for a duplicate but it will take time. Did you end up getting a solution for this and how did you resolve this?